# How to show an activity on opening Device Adminstrator in settings

Tags: android

I want to protect my app from deactivation in device administration settings and want to show an activity with password on open. So that the user can deactivate the app only after entering the password. can anyone help me how to detect when device administration from settings is opened.[image: detect open of this component in settings]